# Where to put custom product properties for Vanilo?

Tags: laravel, vanilo

I'm following the doc here : https://vanilo.io/docs/0.5/properties
It is pretty clear, the only question I have is, under the [Adding Custom Types section](https://vanilo.io/docs/0.5/properties#adding-custom-types) I'm not sure where that custom class is supposed to be ; alongside the Models ? In Middleware ? Or in the **/vendor/vanilo/properties/src/Types/** folder, alongside the other types (*Boolean, Text, Integer, Number*) ?

And once this is done, do I have to do anything else for the new Property to appear in my Product Management UI in Vanilo ?

It seems a very bad idea to create custom properties in the /vendor/ directory, but that's what the doc seems to imply.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer by continuing to tinker.

Under the [Adding Custom Types](https://vanilo.io/docs/0.5/properties#adding-custom-types) section, there are two blocks of code.

The first goes in a file (in their case, the file would probably be Stars.php) that goes directly under \App, alongside the Models. I tried putting it under a /Libs/ subfolder but then I couldn't use it anywhere, not sure why.

The second code block goes, as they mention, in AppServiceProvider.php

Mind the "use" declarations, and make sure that the custom class (in their case, *Stars*) has the two functions *getName()* and *transformValue()*,  both of which are mandatory.